# SharePoint 2010 & Site Minder Custom sign out?

Tags: 2013

Here is my scenario:  We are using two IDP(Identity providers)(ADFS,Site Minder) for our SharePoint Web Application. One TIP (ADFS) is for Internal Users and another TIP(SM) for external Users.

I would like to write a custom sign out page for this  environment.  Please assist.

Thanks